# Akka.Net: Custom table schema for EventJournal in Akka.Persistence.SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, akka.net, akka.net-persistence

Is there an easy way use your own custom table schema when working with Akka.Persistence.SqlServer in Akka.Net?

There is the option to replace the QueryBuilder and QueryMapper, but I can't see a way to replace the default JournalEntry implementation in the DbEngine.

Edit:
Overriding the CopyParamsToCommand method in an inherited version of SqlServerJournalEngine could work? But how to plug that in?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue worth discussing on https://gitter.im/akkadotnet/akka.net channel?